# Accessing superuser.com/users/flag-weight/<username> results in error

Tags: support, flagging

When I try to access `https://superuser.com/users/flag-weight/dragonlord` I get a 500 eror.  However,  accessing https://superuser.com/users/flag-weight/73918 does not.

Can this be handled more gracefully, such as attempting to looking up the correct user ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is this a bug? User names aren't unique. I could change my name to "DragonLord" right now.

Comment: Thank you.  I personally felt that there was a better way to handle this.